# Show rows that appear only once in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I know that we can use unique() to effectively show a dataframe without duplicate values, but is there an elegant way to show only those rows that appear once in a dataframe?

E.g.,

```
a = c(10,20,10,10)
b = c(10,30,10,20)
ab = data.frame(a,b)
```

should return the second and final row only, and not the first and third (since this row exists more than once).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`

```
subset(ab, !(duplicated(ab)|duplicated(ab, fromLast = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
   a  b
2 20 30
4 10 20
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, but could you explain it a little? This is not intuitive to me :)

Comment: @JEDHK `duplicated(ab)` returns a logical vector with TRUE only for the duplicate elements leaving the first element as FALSE, when we do the reverse (fromLast = TRUE), the first occurence is from the last, so it will be FALSE and all other repeats will be TRUE.  Using `|` makes sure that both are considered i.e. `FALSE|TRUE` or `TRUE|FALSE` or `TRUE|TRUE` are all TRUE where as `FALSE|FALSE` is `FALSE`

Comment: I like this mirroring of duplicated very much +1!

Comment: @akrun perfect, a great and concise explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
ab %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   a, b [2]
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    20    30
2    10    20
```